# How can i make the condition so that after read the card in text area, it updates the record that exists before it creates a new one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

https://prnt.sc/IsuRy9OhDic7 Screenshot To check what I am talking about.

- Before it enters a new record it should save the TimeOut("HoraSaida") in the previous record.
- I already did my research but I couldn't find anything that helps me out.
- It reads the card in a text area with event change if it changes it saves the card number, it gets the date of record and the time in(hora entrada).
- When it reads the second time it should save in the field time out (hora saida) before it enters a new record.
- The Last field is a calculated field that gives the worked hours of that day.

Model

```
public partial class entradas_saidas
    {
        public int IdE_S { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdCartao { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DataRegisto { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> HoraEntrada { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> HoraSaida { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> HoraDiarias { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddReport(entradas_saidas es)
        {
            using (EMSistec bd = new EMSistec())
            {
                try
                {
                    
                    bd.entradas_saidas.Add(es);
                    bd.SaveChanges();
                    string message = "SUCCESS";
                    return Json(new { msg = message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet }); 
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    String message = "ERROR";
                    return Json(new { msg = message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
                }           
            }

        }
```

VIEW with Script

```
@using employeeManagement.Models;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@model PagedList.IPagedList<employeeManagement.Models.entradas_saidas>
@*@model IEnumerable<employeeManagement.Models.entradas_saidas>*@

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EntradasSaidas";
}

<h2>EntradasSaidas</h2>
<h4 id="msg" style="color:red">@ViewBag.msg</h4>


@Html.Label("lblsearch", "Leitura do Cartão:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 " })
<textarea style="color:dodgerblue" id="readONchange"></textarea>
<br />



<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "AddEntradasSaidas")
</p>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            #
            @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IdE_S)*@
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Número Cartão", "EntradasSaidas", new { order = ViewBag.idcartao })
            @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IdCartao)*@
        </th>
        <th>
            Data Registo
            @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataRegisto)*@
        </th>
        <th>
            Hora Entrada
            @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HoraEntrada)*@
        </th>
        <th>
            Hora Saída
            @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HoraSaida)*@
        </th>
        <th>
            Horas Diárias
            @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HoraDiarias)*@
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IdE_S)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IdCartao)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataRegisto)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoraEntrada)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoraSaida)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoraDiarias)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditEntradasSaidas", new { id = item.IdE_S }) |
                @*@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |*@
                @*@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteMorada", new { id = item.IdMorada })*@
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", null, null, new { id = item.IdE_S, name = "dellink" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

@((Model.PageNumber > Model.PageCount) ? 1:Model.PageNumber) de @Model.PageCount páginas.
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, (page) => Url.Action("EntradasSaidas", new { page, order = ViewBag.order }))


@*@section readcard{
        <script>
            function readCard() {
                alert("HELLO");
            }

        </script>

    }*@

@section readcard{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#readONchange").change(function () {
                var param1 = new Date();
                var param2 = param1.getDate() + '/' + (param1.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + param1.getFullYear();
                var param3 = param1.getHours() + ':' + param1.getMinutes() + ':' + param1.getSeconds();
                var es = {};
                es.IdCartao = $("#readONchange").val();
                es.DataRegisto = param2;
                if (es.IdCartao == "#readONchange" && es.HoraEntrada == null) {
                    es.HoraEntrada = param3;
                } else {
                    es.HoraSaida = param3;
                }
                alert("AGORA AQUI")
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("AddReport")',
                    data: '{es: ' + JSON.stringify(es) + '}',
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    sucess: function () {
                        alert("Dado inserido com sucesso");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("ERRO! Nao foi possivel");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

}

@section esDelete{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("[name='dellink']").click((evt) => {
                evt = evt ? evt : window.event;
                evt.preventDefault();
                if (!confirm("Tem a certeza que quer apagar o registo?")) return false;
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteEntradasSaidas")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { id: evt.target.id },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                        if (data.msg == "Registo apagado com sucesso!") $(evt.target).closest('tr').remove();
                        $("h4").html(data.msg);
                    },
                    error: function () { alert("Erro ao apagar registo!");}
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

Comment: Note that `return Json(new { msg = message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });` returns JSON like `{ "msg": "whatever was in message", "AllowGet": 0 }`. If you want to allow GET requests when returning JSON, use `return Json(new { msg = message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`. In other words, pass the enum as a parameter to the `Json` function.

Comment: As for the issue, you're passing the *JSON stringified* value of `es` to your action, not an `entradas_saidas` object, so either change `AddReport` to take `string es` and parse it as JSON, or change your script to pass `{ es: es }` (or just `{ es }` without translating it to a string (jQuery will automatically do that).

Comment: Yes, I already changed that, it was my mistake.